# Pyspark Dataframe number of rows too large, how to avoid failure trying to count()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to run some spark jobs.. when `df.count()` gets called, I get the following stack trace:

Starting the job...

```
Starting job: count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0
Registering RDD 24 (count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) as input to shuffle 0
Got job 2 (count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) with 1 output partitionsFinal stage: Result
Stage 3 (count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0)
Submitting ShuffleMapStage 2 (MapPartitionsRDD[24] at count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0), which has no missing parents
Submitting 5 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 2 (MapPartitionsRDD[24] at count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

After failure....

```
the Job 2 failed: count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0, took 32.116609 s
INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 2 (count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) failed in 32.053 s due to Stage cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
```

Looks like the number of rows is just way too large. Im very new to spark, is there a way to handle this? Maybe a config option?

Comment: pls show code...

Comment: increase the partition by df.repatition(2000).count()